# When pg_restore honours --dbname option

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to restore a binary `pg_dump` backup under a different database name that was in the original dump. Despite giving `--dbname` command line argument, `pg_restore` tries to restore everything under the original database name - the behavior I especially want to avoid.

```
createdb mydb

pg_restore --dbname=mydb --exit-on-error -Fc database.bak

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 8; 2615 16396 SCHEMA topology u9o2f4j0
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  schema "topology" already exists
    Command was: CREATE SCHEMA topology;
```

How can I make `pg_restore` to restore the database under a different name?

```
pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.5.5

pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1
```

Comment: Edited the question, leaving out `--create` doesn't change anything

Comment: sure? "When this option is used, the database named with -d is used only to issue the initial DROP DATABASE and CREATE DATABASE commands. All data is restored into the database name that appears in the archive." is for `-C` so it looked like your case

Comment: Your example code (without the --create) works for me.  Are you sure that your `createdb mydb` succeeded, rather than failing because mydb already existed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few command line options you need to consider.

```
  pg_restore -x --no-owner --dbname=mynewdb --exit-on-error -Fc database.bak
```

- `-Fc`: restore from a binary back up as its more flexible than plain text SQL dump
- `--dbname`: restore under this database name (must be created beforehand using `createdb`)
- `-x`: do not try to restore access priviledges (e.g. the superuser name may change between databases)
- `--no-owner`: the database owner user is different on the system where restore is performed
- `--exit-on-error`: If bad stuff happens, abort and don't flood your terminal with useless errors